# asterisk letter wrong alignment java

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

When I view list item with a text aligned to right in Arabic language, wrong formatting occurs.
In all Arabic statements, it works fine. [arWord].25.3 but only when the text is `*` it looks like this.
Result  : `.22.1.*`

CODE:

```
arabicFormat = String.format(new Locale(Language.Arabic.getCode(),
                    Language.Arabic.getCountry()), "%d.%d.%s",position,
                    (h.getSeq() + 1), navText);
```

**Expected**: `*.22.1`    [asterisk at the left]

**Result**  : `.22.1.*`

EDIT:
The problem appeared also with other characters like ، '.

Comment: in other arabic words it works fine. arWord.25.3 but only when the text is * it looks like this.

Comment: is `navText` the asterisk?

Comment: yes. When it is asterisk, this problem occurs. any other words works fine

Comment: Well the asterisk is the last part of the format. Maybe you should put it in the front if thats how you wan it

Comment: So you think the problem is asterisk specific or any special character ?

Comment: You need to provide some examples

Answer (score 4):

This is a very interesting problem. I decided to play around with it more, and yes, I can replicate your problem here. My take is `*` is not an Arabic text, thus it doesn't apply the language format on it.

Here are the my tests:-

```
@Test
public void testArabicLanguage() {
    // arabic
    assertThat(toArabicLanguage("قضاة وحقوقيون يكشفون "), is("22.1.قضاة وحقوقيون يكشفون "));

    // english
    assertThat(toArabicLanguage("hey"), is("22.1.hey"));

    // chinese
    assertThat(toArabicLanguage("现在进入"), is("22.1.现在进入"));

    // symbol
    assertThat(toArabicLanguage("*"), is("22.1.*"));
}

private String toArabicLanguage(String navText) {
    String s = String.format(new Locale("ar", "DZ"), "%d.%d.%s", 22, 1, navText);
    System.out.println(s);
    return s;
}
```

When I executed the above tests, everything passed.

However, when I viewed the console printout and the test directly in IntelliJ, I'm seeing the Arabic text displayed right-to-left.

Whenever I copy and paste the text here, it's always displayed left-to-right.

Here's the console printout:-

```
22.1.قضاة وحقوقيون يكشفون 
22.1.hey
22.1.现在进入
22.1.*
```

Now, compare that to what I see in IntelliJ, the Arabic text is displayed right-to-left instead:-

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

If all you want is to always display `navText` first, you could use [language-detection](https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/) library to do so. This library seems to require [jsonic](http://jsonic.sourceforge.jp/) library in order for it to work... yes, I know it's in Japanese, and I don't read Japanese myself... just find `jsonic 1.3 (1.3.0)` and download that.

With this, you can do something like this:-

```
public class MyTest {

    // language-detection zip file comes with a `profile` dir... just point to it.
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        try {
            DetectorFactory.loadProfile("/path/to/language-detection/profiles");
        }
        catch (LangDetectException e) {
            fail("Can't locate the language profiles");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testArabicLanguage() {
        // arabic
        assertThat(toArabicLanguage("قضاة وحقوقيون يكشفون "), is("22.1.قضاة وحقوقيون يكشفون "));

        // english
        assertThat(toArabicLanguage("hey"), is("hey.22.1"));

        // chinese
        assertThat(toArabicLanguage("现在进入"), is("现在进入.22.1"));

        // symbol
        assertThat(toArabicLanguage("*"), is("*.22.1"));
    }

    private String toArabicLanguage(String navText) {
        boolean isArabicLanguage = false;

        try {
            Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create();
            detector.append(navText);

            isArabicLanguage = detector.detect().equals("ar");
        }
        catch (LangDetectException e) {
            // `*` will throw this exception:-
            // "com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.LangDetectException: no features in text"
            //
            // so, just catch it and treat it as non-Arabic language.
        }

        if (isArabicLanguage) {
            return String.format(new Locale("ar", "DZ"), "%d.%d.%s", 22, 1, navText);
        }
        else {
            return String.format("%s.%d.%d", navText, 22, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this solution is a little overkill, and it may have unintended side effects on non-Arabic languages.

Comment: but the output here looks 22.1.* , I need it to be *.22.1 like the Arabic letters.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved by adding this unicode `\u200F` character before the letters. It enforced the right to left for anything :

```
arabicFormat = String.format(new Locale(Language.Arabic.getCode(),
                    Language.Arabic.getCountry()), "%d.%d.\u200F%s", 22,
                    1, navText);
```